# Any way to invoke PostgreSql procedure without return value using java?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Recently, I have created a postgresql's function likes below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION POSTPRC(A IN NUMERIC)
**RETURNS VOID**
AS
$$
BEGIN
... ...
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

How can I invoke it using java, I have used the code likes below:

```
CallableStatement upperProc = con.prepareCall("{ ? = call POSTPRC( ? ) }");
upperProc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.NULL);
upperProc.setInt(2,23);
int flag=upperProc.executeUpdate();
```

but errors will occur every time, how to do can resolved this problem?

The Exception show as:**java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2.**

The Procedure POSTPRC with correspond parameters can successfully execute at pgAdminIII tool.

---

The postgresql should use the statement likes-{? = call procedure(?,?,?)}, and this is the only way to invoke through java. I have tested the statement likes {call procedure(?,?,?)} etc. Failed every time. Actually, postgresql's procedure is function, if we want to invoke the procedure of postgresql, we'd better to define the postgresql's procedure with out parameters or return values....

**Any comments are welcome!**

Thanks

Comment: please post full stack trace (add to answer)

Comment: Try `registerOutParameter(1, Types.OTHER);`

Comment: Could you try it with `{?=call(?)}`, but without registering an out parameter and setting parameter 1 (not 2) to the value to be passed to the stored procedure. Maybe postgresql misbehaves here.

Comment: Hi,Mark Thank you very much! I have tried as you recommend but failed. It seems that the values cannot corresponds with right place... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure, why do you need the first `?` if your function does not return a value. You can as well write it

```
CallableStatement upperProc = con.prepareCall("{call POSTPRC( ? ) }");
```

Have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html)

By the way, if your function does not return a value, then you don't need to do it with CallableStatements - you can/should just as well use a PreparedStatement:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM POSTPRC( ? )")
pstmt.setInt(1,23);
pstmt.execute(); // omit the result
```

Comment: Hi,agim Invoking postgresql should use {? = CALL POSTPRC(?) } Only. I had tried {CALL POSTPRC(?)} but failed...Thanks.

Comment: @Edward didn't know that. Did you try with `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: Yes, the specified value cannot be placed in '?' of POSTPRC(?).At this point i have tried statement {Call POSTPRC(?)} ... Thanks!